# When you uninstall an application by using the control panel what commands are running?

Tags: windows, cmd, office365, controlpanel

If I go to the control panel and uninstall Microsoft Office the program uninstalls. How is that application actually being uninstalled? Is it a command line? If so is there a log or something I can check for what commands are being run?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control panel/settings app just executes the command stored in the [`UninstallString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx) value in the registry.

Logging is done by the uninstaller, not Windows. You can manually look at the `UninstallString` value in the registry, if it uses Msiexec (Windows Installer) then you can manually execute Msiexec with the [logging parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490936.aspx):

```
Msiexec /x{productid} /L*v c:\mylogfile.log
```

If it is using some other installer technology then you have to consult the products documentation or contact the developer to find out if there is a way to enable logging.